# Several paste() calls inside an if statement, first call does not work but the 2nd does

Tags: r, if-statement, paste

This post [Paste() function in loop/if seems to be not working as intended in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56878199/paste-function-in-loop-if-seems-to-be-not-working-as-intended-in-r) led me to try to understand how paste() works inside an if statement.

My answer on that post is definitely a me too answer, but a comment just doesn't capture the formatting, so here is the question:

How does paste behave inside an if () statement?

I'm getting the 2nd paste to print, but not the first. I expected the first to print, but not the second.

```
x <- 1
y <- 2

if(x < y){

  print("test print")
  
  paste("Test paste...x is:", x)  #why doesn't this print, but the next paste does? 
  
  paste("Y  is:", y)
}


[1] "test print"
[1] "Y  is: 2"
```

Why didn't the first paste line print, but the 2nd did?

**Edit:**

Even if I remove all of the print calls, the first paste doesn't not print, but the 2nd does:

```
x=1
y=2
if(x<y){

paste("Test paste, x is :", x)
paste("2nd test paste, y  is:", y)
}

[1] "2nd test paste, y  is: 2"
```

Comment: Well, if one removes the print, then the behavior remains.  I've updated the question to show that if you have 2 paste statements, the first doesn't print.  

I think I'm really asking how does an if() statement work.  I get that print() will work, I don't understand why the first paste does not.

Comment: @akrun's comment is still correct with your change:  the last one prints because it is the value of the expression.  The first one isn't.

Comment: R has two printing behaviors: 1) triggered by functions like `print` which specifically prints its argument 2) running a function or a command or a set of commands grouped within `{ }` will print out the output of that / those commands.

Comment: I was just about to write this comment when I was bumped off my machine:

This is the information I needed:

"R returns the last expression"

I was in the middle of thanking @akrun for that bit  when I had to change computers.  

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding what `paste()` does.  It *never* prints anything.  It just computes a character vector.

If that computation happens to be the last line in a block of code in braces entered at the console, its value will be printed.

This is similar to what happens in an R function:  you can call `paste()` as much as you like there, but nothing will print.  If the last statement in the function happens to be a call to `paste()`, then the function will return that value.  And if the function call happens to be the last (or only) statement in a top-level block of statements, auto-printing will print it.

Comment: I think I misunderstood how an if statement works. I understand that paste doesn't print anything...it was in the context of how it works in the if statement.  But thank you for trying to help.